# BATCH file to copy specific text and past after X in multiple .txt files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I started learning Batch files commands and I succeeded to create some basic scripts to simplify some tasks at work.
Now I'm looking to automate a repetitive task that takes a lot of time to be done... and to say I'm doing it manually each day :
I have a bunch of .txt files grouped in the same folder and the content of these texte files is like below :

---

Comments lines

**START**    (name of electronic component) (Number of pins)

Program body line 1

Program body line 2

.

Program body line X

**END**

Comments lines

---

What I'm doing is to copy the "name of the electronic part" that I'm working on 
 and paste it after END. Here is an example :

---

**START**     BC547   3

Program body line 1

Program body line 2

.

Program body line X

**END** BC547

---

There are numerous blank END in the same file, you can imagine filling 200 to 300 text files every day manually ...

In some cases the structure changes to :

---

Comments lines

**START**  (name1) (Number of pins)

Comments lines

**START**  (subcircuit1) (Number of pins)

Program body line 1

.

Program body line X

**END** (subcircuit1)

Comments lines

**START**  (subcircuit2) (Number of pins)

Program body line 1

.

Program body line X

**END** (subcircuit2)

Comments lines

**START**  (subcircuitx) (Number of pins)

Program body line 1

.

Program body line X

**END** (subcircuitx)

Comments lines

**END** (name1)

Comments lines

---

I would be much thankful if someone can make batch code to copy the full next word after START and paste it in the next END below. The script have to be able to detetct the second case when STAR syntaxes are consecutive.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This site does not provide a free coding service for people. Here you request help with specific problems encountered as a result of invoking your own code. In that scenario you'd post the relevant portion of code and fully explain the issues noted. _If you'd prefer to hire somebody, then please state your terms._

Answer (score 1):

The community has determined that open ended questions asking for de novo code to meet a set of business requirements is out of scope for StackOverflow [batchfile](/questions/tagged/batchfile) questions. But I am bored and couldn't help myself.

The algorithm is fairly strait forward. Iterate all the lines of the source file. If the line begins with START, then parse out the ID and push the value on a stack (array). If the line begins with END then append the last stack value to the line and pop the stack. If the line does not begin with END then simply write the original line.

But nothing in batch is simple.

- FOR /F disregards lines that are empty, so FINDSTR /N is used to prefix each line with a line number, followed by a colon. String manipulation is performed within the loop to strip off the line number prefix.
- Batch doesn't have formal support for arrays, but the code shows how to emulate arrays.
- Delayed expansion is required within a parenthesized block of code, so an array member may not be accessed as `!ID.%i%`. The code shows how to transfer the current `i` value to a FOR variable so you can use `!ID.%%I` instead.
- Delayed expansion is toggled ON and OFF within the loop to protect any `!` that may be present within the source file.
- You cannot write to the file you are reading from. So the result must be written to a temporary new file, which is later MOVEd to replace the original.

The script below should be called with one or more file masks that specify which files should be processed. If the script is named "fixEnd.bat", then `fixEnd test.txt` would process test.txt in the current directory. `fixEnd "c:\somePath\*.txt"` would process all .txt files within the "c:\somePath" folder. `fixEnd file1.txt file2.txt` would process those two files in the current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (%*) do (
  set /a i=0
  set "ID.0="
  >"%%F.new" (
    for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" "test.txt"') do for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=: " %%A in ("%%L") do (
      if "%%B" == "START" (
        set /a i+=1
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        for %%I in (!i!) do (
          endlocal
          set "ID.%%I=%%C"
        )
      )
      if "%%B" == "END" (
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        for %%I in (!i!) do (
          (echo END !ID.%%I!)
          endlocal
          set "ID.%%I="
          set /a "1/i, i-=1)" 2>nul %= division by zero error prevents negative i values =%
        )
      ) else (
        set "ln=%%L"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        (echo(!ln:*:=!)
        endlocal
      )
    )
  )
  move /y "%%~F.new" "%%F" >nul
)
```

As much as I enjoy the challenge of working with batch, I long ago came to the conclusion that it is not practical to use pure batch to manipulate text files except for really simple cases. And in many cases batch simply is not up to the task. Which is why I wrote [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), a regular expression text processing utility that is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

JREPL has myriad options that give it tremendous power, especially the ability to incorporate user supplied JScript on the command line. Using JREPL, the same algorithm is implemented in a much more straightforward way, and the code is ***much*** faster than pure batch:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (%*) do for %%F in (test.txt) do call jrepl^
  "^START\b\s*(\S*)/^END\b.*"^
  "id[id.length]=$2;$txt=$0/$txt='END '+(id.length?id[id.length-1]:'');id=id.slice(0,-1)"^
  /jbeg "var i=0, id=[]" /t "/" /jq /f "%%F" /o -
```

Use `jrepl /??` from the command line to view the entire documentation, one screen at a time. `jrepl /?help` lists all available types of help. `jrepl /?options` gives a brief summary of all available options. `jrepl /?/t` would show the help for the `/T` option. Etc.